# java.lang.NullPointerException with data from xml

Tags: java, android

I have the following error:

```
02-28 15:57:30.866: W/dalvikvm(4610): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.xuexiaozhe.xml.Mp3ListContentHandler.characters(Mp3ListContentHandler.java:51)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:163)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendChars(Native Method)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:497)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:484)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:309)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:267)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.xuexiaozhe.list.RemoteMp3ListActivity.parseMp3Info(RemoteMp3ListActivity.java:188)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.xuexiaozhe.list.RemoteMp3ListActivity.access$1(RemoteMp3ListActivity.java:178)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.xuexiaozhe.list.RemoteMp3ListActivity$NetworkHandler.handleMessage(RemoteMp3ListActivity.java:109)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-28 15:57:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 15:57:31.005: D/dalvikvm(4610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 9% free 6016K/6596K, paused 89ms+86ms, total 267ms
```

Mp3ListContentHandler class code:

```
    package com.xuexiaozhe.xml;

import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.xuexiaozhe.model.Mp3Info;

public class Mp3ListContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private List<Mp3Info> mp3Infos = null;
    private Mp3Info mp3Info = null;
    private String tagName = null;

    private static final String XML_RESOURCE_TAG = "resource";
    private static final String XML_ID_TAG = "id";
    private static final String XML_TITLE_TAG = "title";
    private static final String XML_ARTIST_TAG = "artist";
    private static final String XML_ALBUM_TAG = "album";
    private static final String XML_DURATION_TAG = "duration";
    private static final String XML_MP3NAME_TAG = "mp3Name";
    private static final String XML_MP3SIZE_TAG = "mp3Size";
    private static final String XML_LRCNAME_TAG = "lrcName";
    private static final String XML_LRCSIZE_TAG = "lrcSize";
    private static final String XML_BACKGROUND_TAG = "background";

    public Mp3ListContentHandler(List<Mp3Info> mp3Infos) {
        super();
        this.mp3Infos = mp3Infos;
    }

    public List<Mp3Info> getMp3Infos() {

        return mp3Infos;

    }

    public void setMp3Infos(List<Mp3Info> mp3Infos) {
        this.mp3Infos = mp3Infos;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // ¸ّmp3Infoةèضأµؤب«تاخؤ¼‏أû£¬£¬¸ù¾فxmlخؤ¼‏ض±½سةèضأ£¬´ّخؤ¼‏أû؛َ×؛
        String temp = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (XML_ID_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setId(Integer.parseInt(temp));
        } else if (XML_TITLE_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setTitle(temp);
        } else if (XML_ARTIST_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setArtist(temp);
        } else if (XML_ALBUM_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setAlbum(temp);
        } else if (XML_DURATION_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setDuration(Long.parseLong(temp));
        } else if (XML_MP3NAME_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setMp3Name(temp);
        } else if (XML_MP3SIZE_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setMp3Size(Long.parseLong(temp));
        } else if (XML_LRCNAME_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setLrcName(temp);
        } else if (XML_LRCSIZE_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setLrcSize(Long.parseLong(temp));
        } else if (XML_BACKGROUND_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setBackgroundName(temp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (XML_RESOURCE_TAG.equals(qName)) {
            mp3Infos.add(mp3Info);
        }
        tagName = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

    }



        @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

        tagName = localName;
        if (tagName.equals("resource")) {
            mp3Info = new Mp3Info();
        }
    }

    public Mp3Info getMp3Info() {
        return mp3Info;
    }

    public void setMp3Info(Mp3Info mp3Info) {
        this.mp3Info = mp3Info;
    }

    public List<Mp3Info> getmp3Infos() {
        return mp3Infos;
    }

    public void setMp3List(List<Mp3Info> mp3Infos) {
        this.mp3Infos = mp3Infos;
    }

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is line 51? There is NPE.

Comment: Please post your `Mp3ListContentHandler` class.

Comment: I have modified the post

Comment: line 51         } else if (XML_TITLE_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
            mp3Info.setTitle(temp);

Answer (score 0):

The `mp3Info` variable isn't initialized, it is set to `null`.

Indeed, at the line 13:

```
private Mp3Info mp3Info = null;
```

It should be initialized in the method `startElement`, but I don't know when and where you invoke this method.

Comment: private String tagName;
the same problem :*_*:

Comment: @user3245604 Yes, it's the same for that variable. It should initialized in the `startElement` method.

Comment: can you please do it for me ^_^

Comment: @user3245604 Do what? What I can do is to give you the following advice. Review your logic and make those variables initialized :)

Comment: i did it     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, please see end the class , same problem

Comment: @user3245604 Same problem at the same line? Make sure that `localName` parameter is initialized. If not, you'll have a NPE in `tagName.equals("resource"))` Post your new stacktrace.

Comment: yes same line , my problem withe read xml file from web quirksaio.xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems your mp3Info class field is null. So as i see from code you've posted the only way to set mp3Info is here

`if (XML_RESOURCE_TAG.equals(tagName)) {
     mp3Info = new Mp3Info();
 }`

so you can check mp3Info for null in your characters method before if statement:
something like

```
if (mp3Info == null) {
    mp3Info = new Mp3Info();
}
```

And another cause of it as i see is only if method startElement never gets localName with value "resource"